# What's the correct way to import angular-mocks to prevent TS errors?

Tags: angularjs, typescript2.0, angular-mock

I've updated an angular 1 project from TS 1.8 to TS 2.0 and am using `@types/angular-mocks` for the type definitions. As it stands, i'm unable to work out how to actually import and use `angular-mocks` `module`, without getting TS errors.

All three of these ways actually work (as in, the transpiled code passes all tests and runs without error in the browser), but they all result in TS errors

**1)**

```
import {module} from 'angular-mocks';

beforeEach(module('blah'));
```

systemjs config meta:

```
meta: {
    angular: {
        format: 'global',
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular-mocks': {
        format: 'global',
        deps: ['angular']
    }
}
```

TS error:

`error TS2305: Module '"/path/to/node_modules/@types/angular-mocks/index"' has no exported member 'module'.`

**2)**

```
import * as angular from 'angular-mocks';

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('blah'));
```

systemjs config meta:

```
meta: {
    angular: {
        format: 'global',
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular-mocks': {
        format: 'global',
        exports: 'angular',
        deps: ['angular']
    }
}
```

TS error:

`error TS2339: Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'typeof "/path/to/node_modules/@types/angular...'.`

**3)**

```
import 'angular-mocks';

beforeEach(module('blah'));
```

systemjs config meta:

```
meta: {
    angular: {
        format: 'global',
        exports: 'angular'
    },
    'angular-mocks': {
        format: 'global',
        deps: ['angular']
    }
}
```

TS Error:

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.`

---

**Question**

So i'm wondering what's the correct way to do this to prevent TS errors?